# Setup an existing Digital Ocean Droplet to use my ssh key

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, digital-ocean

I have created a public and private key so that I can SSH into my Digital Ocean droplet. However I created the droplet before I created my key so [this walk through](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-keys-with-putty-on-digitalocean-droplets-windows-users) stops helping me mid way through. Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2qZSpp5Chk&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBpuvPW0aHa7mKdn_k9SPKO&index=29) I tried copying my key to the correct places but I have failed because I still can't login without entering my password.

Here is what I have:

- A public key.
- A private key.
- A Digital Ocean droplet.
- `root` user.
- `my_name` user with sudo access.

I just don't understand where I need to be copy and pasting my public key.

This is what I see when I first login.

```
indevoid@droplet001:~$ dir
indevoid@droplet001:~$
```

Can you please show me step by step what I need to do? You can explain the steps if you like but I will be looking up the ones I don't understand while I'm going through the steps.

Comment: You are going to have to log into your VPS, with a username and password and upload the keys to your server, have you done that?

Comment: @Ramhound I think I have. When I type `dir` it shows nothing but there is still a `.ssh` folder I can `cd` into. When I'm in the `.ssh` folder I see `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, a Digital Ocean “droplet” is simply a Linux server of some kind. And at the end of the day what you want/need is password-less SSH access. Knowing that, this is how you can set this up on your setup or practically any Linux/*nix setup; including macOS.

First, be sure to check the `.ssh/` directory for the user you wish to have password-less access on the droplet. The permissions for that directory should be `700` (aka: `drwx------`). So run this command to change those permissions on those directories:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

And past that, you need to create a `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file that contains the text of any/all authorized keys you plan on using with that login. Such as the `id_rsa.pub` file contents. Copy the contents of that file into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

And make sure that file has `600` permissions (aka: `-rw-------`). So run this command to change those permissions:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

These commands prepended with `~/` assume you are logged in as the user that has access to that `.ssh` directory. So adjust the path to match your needs.